# How to inverse a shape in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes

I have a shape that is basically the inverse of the shape I am trying to make. I have the outline of the shape and a square around it, but what I want is the shape inside of it.

What I have: (black is the shape)
[image]

[image: what I want]

Comment: Select the outer shape curve and hit delete.

Comment: I never expected that to work, but it did, thanks.